# Spring Boot, update frontend without restarting the application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

In the Spring Boot make the frontend part update without restarting the application?

Comment: What do you mean specifically by "frontend"?  JSPs?  Thymeleaf?  HTML + JS files?

Comment: HTML + CSS + JS without JSP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm an Eclipse user (via Spring Tool Suite) and I never have any problems with reloading static content if the app is running in debug mode. Just right click on the main class and "Debug As->Java App" (or "Spring Boot App", it's the same). You have to also ensure that the workspace is configured to "Build Automatically", but that is the default as far as I know.

I can't offer such specific advice for users of other IDEs, but I'm sure they all have the same feature.

Answer (score 12):

Best solution i found for static webpages and css is
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39334398/6467734
and for loading code (including jsp) without restarting the server you can use Spring Boot Devtools dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

In the Intellij IDEA run up your project in **Debug** mode and you will get the same effect.

Or externalize your static .

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private String extStaticPath = "/var/www/site1/";

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations(extStaticPath)
                .setCachePeriod(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for JSP files try to set `server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.development=true`

Comment: Bro, you saved my life.

Comment: I suppose the property's name should be --server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.development=true. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72687339/9826710

Answer (score 1):

You can try [developer tools](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) from Spring boot. Applications that use spring-boot-devtools will automatically restart whenever files on the classpath change. More info how it works [here](https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-developer-tools/)