# Command Line Argument servlet.init-parameters.development=true has no effect in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, servlets, tomcat9

I run a Spring-Boot application (v2.7) via Eclipse Run configuration. In the *Program arguments* section, I pass the parameter

```
--server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.development=true
```

But this doesn't seem to have any effect. When running the application, `pageContext.getServletConfig().getInitParameter("development")` returns `false`.

There is no other location where the `init-parameters` property is set.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**: when I set the parameter in (already existing) application.yaml it works.

```
server:
  servlet:
    jsp:
      init-parameters:
        development: true
```

But I need to set it via command line ...

Comment: The property name on the command line doesn't match the property name in your YAML file. To match, it should be `--server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.development`

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo. The correct argument is:

```
--server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.development=true
```

This works as expected.

I copied the wrong value from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60074764/9826710 ...